# Реализация кастомного протокола поверх TCP на android

Tags: java, android, tcp

Требуется реализовать передачу массива байт по TCP протоколу. Протокол кастомный: первые 3 байта будут постоянно меняться, далее 2 байта всегда статичны, и следующие 2 байта будут постоянно меняться. Подскажите как правильно реализовать такую структуру или что почитать на эту тему.
С таким еще никогда не сталкивался и я не имею малейшего представления как это сделать.

Можно попробовать создать отдельный класс с геттерами/сеттерами и вызывать его при инициализации отправляемого массива.

Comment: можно отправить сокетами. `Socket socket = new Socket("", 8800);
        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
        sout.write(bytes);` Ну а вообще почитайте в этом направлении

Comment: @Виктор передачу между клиентом сервером я наладил. Меня интересует момент укомплектовки массива байт. Как я написал в вопросе, там некоторые байты меняются, некотоыре статичны и записаны как константы. По поводу почитать в этом направлении, я не нашел ничего, скорее всего не правильно гуглю. просто не знаю в каком направлении копать)